# Unable to find Resource using RT_RCDATA

Tags: resources

I have an application where I have wave files embedded as resources. The wave files are added as Custom Resources under the type "WAVE".

Now, I am trying to retrieve the embedded wave files using FindResource() and LoadResource().

Now here's the problem: I am able to find the bitmap resource using FindResource() but NOT the Wave resources. I am using RT_RCDATA as ResourceType. Here's the code snippet:

```
// Load the .EXE file that contains the dialog box you want to copy.
hExe = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\ExternalResource.exe"));
if (hExe == NULL)
{
    //ErrorHandler(TEXT("Could not load exe."));
    return 0;
}

// Locate the Testsong200 resource in the .EXE file.
//hRes = FindResource(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(104), RT_BITMAP);
hRes = FindResource(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(105), RT_RCDATA);
if (hRes == NULL)
{
    //ErrorHandler(TEXT("Could not locate dialog box."));
    return 0;
}
```

The hRes returns NULL when I use RT_RCDATA.

Any pointers in the right direction will make my day :)

regards,
andy.

P.S I tried to upload the screenshot but realised that I need to have 10 rep points to upload one :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, Got it.

I need to use FindResource in the following way:

```
hRes = FindResource(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(105), _T("WAVE"));
```

regards,
andy